# Can't resize APFS container

Tags: hard-drive, partition, disk-space

On a 120GB SSD hard drive in a MacBook only 68.68GB are available. The missing 51.32GB are not even shown as a free space.

Here is what the output of Disk Utility looks like:
[image: disk0]

[image: disk1]

[image: disk1s1]

[image: terminal screen]

As you can see on the first screenshot the disk has 120GB. However, the partition chart on the same screenshot only shows 68.7GB. Also the other two screenshots show that only 68.7GB out of 120GB seem to be available.

The command diskutil list shows that the physical disk0 is 120GB big, but the synthesized disk1 only 68.7GB:

[image: disk info]

Comment: i have tried to run in the terminal: "diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 110g"but the output was: "Aligning grow delta to 41,317,806,080 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 109,999,996,928 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 68,682,190,848 bytes
Error: -69771: The target disk is too small for this operation
". I have tried the same from the Recovery Mode - but output was the same

Comment: Add to your question the output from the commands: `diskutil info disk0s1 | grep -e "Offset" -e "Disk Size"` and `diskutil info disk0s2 | grep -e "Offset" -e "Disk Size"`

Comment: @DavidAnderson, done

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record. I've managed to increase the size of my APFS volume using GParted and Disk Utility (from macOS Catalina).

1. Create a GParted USB drive and boot from it
2. Use GParted to move the APFS partition/container around so that the free space appears *directly **AFTER*** the APFS partition.
3. Boot into Mac Recovery mode and open Disk Utility
4. Click the drop-down in the top left and enable "Show All Devices"
5. Select your SSD (top entry)
6. Click "Partition"
7. Somewhat unintuitive, but now select the "Free Space" area and click the "-" button below. This will "remove" the free space and enlarge the APFS container to fill it.
8. Confirm the dialog and the resizing should start.
9. Done.

Comment: I just ignored apple's silly warning that adding a volume is easier than partitioning. It was easy to do step 6/7/8.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the offsets and sizes of the two partitions on the drive.

The offset of `disk0s1` is `409,600` bytes.
The size of `disk0s1` is `209,715,200` bytes.

The offset of `disk0s2` is `51,351,912,448` bytes.
The size of `disk0s2` is `68,682,190,848` bytes.

Using the above data, the space between the partitions can be computed, as shown below.

```
(size of disk0s2) - (size of disk0s1) - (offset of disk0s1)
= 51,351,912,448 bytes - 209,715,200 bytes - 409,600 bytes
= 51,141,787,648 bytes (approximately 51.1 GB)
```

The command given below adds free space found immediately *after* `disk0s2` back to the APFS container inside the partition.

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0
```

Since the `51.1 GB` of free space occurs immediately *before* `disk0s2`, the command given above **will not be able** to return this free space back to the APFS container.

The easiest course for action would be to backup, erase the drive and reload. While it may be possible to use macOS to fix the drive without using a backup, this would require creating two APFS containers on the same drive. Apple did not design macOS to handle multiple APFS containers on the same drive and should only be attempted by advanced users.

Another possible solution would be to use third party software to move the APFS container partition (`disk0s2`). One possible pay utility is offered by [Paragon](https://www.paragon-software.com/hdm-mac/). The free [GNOME Partition Editor (GParted)](https://gparted.org) utility reports being able to move APFS partitions.

### How to Create a GParted Bootable Flash Drive

> Note: The operating system was macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

1. Download the [gparted-live-0.33.0-2-amd64.zip](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.33.0-2/) file. I assume this file will download to your `Downloads` folder. After the download completes, the zip file will be automatically convert to a folder named `gparted-live-0`.
2. Use the Disk Utility application to erase a `500 MB` or larger flash drive. Select the options shown below.

   [image: t1]
3. Using the Finder application, open the folder named `gparted-live-0`. The contents are shown below. Use the Finder application to copy the contents to the flash drive.

   [image: t2]

### How to Boot from a GParted Flash Drive

> Note: This was tested using an iMac (21.5 inch, Late 2013) with the latest firmware updates installed.

1. Insert the flash drive in a USB port on the Mac.
2. Restart the Mac and immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key.
3. When the Startup Manager icons appears, choose the external drive icon labeled `EFI Boot`.

When prompted, I choose the default startup option.

Comment: so, @David Anderson, please confirm - The easiest way is to erase the drive, it's not a problem for me, because there is no my data on this Mac, and I even do not need to make a backup, but I already tried it, I have erased the hard drive and it didn't helps me, so please confirm - maybe I have done something wrong

Comment: Do you boot from the internet, flash drive or other media before attempting to erase the drive?

Comment: I just switched to Recovery mode by holding cmd+r,and than from Disk Utility erased a Macintosh HD

Comment: My instructions stated to ***erase the drive***. You erased the `Macintosh HD` volume. You can not erase the drive while booted to the drive. So, if you booted from the recover volume on the drive, then you will not be able to erase the drive. You can erase the drive, if you boot from Internet recovery or a USB flash drive macOS installer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all -  want to say "Thanks a lot" to @David Anderson, with his help i have resolved my issue:
 1. Enter Internet Recovery Mode - restart you mac and hold alt + cmd + r ;
 2. Open "Disk Utility" from the macOS Utilities window;
 3. Erase the Macintosh HD in the Container disk1;
 4. Erase the top hard drive "ADATA SP580 Media" (APPLE SSD);
 5. Close the Disk Utility window and choose "Reinstall macOS" from the macOS Utilities window - follow the instructions

PS. If you want to save your data - you need to make a Time Machine backup before